# Not SELECTing a row if it is empty

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with a query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PointPerson
FROM DailyTaskHours
WHERE ActivityDate BETWEEN @startDateParam
        AND @endDateParam
GROUP BY PointPerson
HAVING SUM([Hours]) > 0
ORDER BY PointPerson
```

This is what it is returning:

[image]

As you can see the first value being returned is an empty string. How do I prevent this row from being returned in the query. If empty dont return..

Comment: You could normalize your tables ;)

Comment: They aren't my tables =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just add a condition in your `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT PointPerson
FROM DailyTaskHours
WHERE ActivityDate BETWEEN @startDateParam AND @endDateParam
    AND PointPerson <> ''
GROUP BY PointPerson
HAVING SUM([Hours]) > 0
ORDER BY PointPerson
```

There are lot of variations of this condition, depending on how your tables are normalized.

If you are sure you will always have a blank space, then you can use:

`AND PointPerson <> ''`

If it is possible to have a **NULL** value, the it's most wise to use:

`AND ISNULL(PointPerson, '') <> ''`

If it is possible to have spaces in that field (they would apper as blanks, but would still not be caught by the first option), the you could use an additional condition along with a combination with the first two, which provides the safest option (covers the most cases):

```
AND ISNULL(PointPerson, '') <> ''
AND LEN(LTRIM(PointPerson)) > 0
```

This combination of conditions will help you avoid NULL values, and multiple whitespaces which are going to be eliminated by trimming them with `LTRIM`, whose result will have to have at least one character.

Comment: you can use `len` instead using both `<>''` and `null` :)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Yes, but what if he has whitespaces? Those have LEN > 0, but should not be displayed.

Comment: Yes, I have answerd that in my answer!

Comment: @huMptyduMpty Sorry, I didn't see that.

Answer (score 1):

Also Consider null values (if you need to)

```
SELECT DISTINCT PointPerson
FROM DailyTaskHours
WHERE ActivityDate BETWEEN @startDateParam
        AND @endDateParam
     AND isnull(PointPersonm,'') <> ''
GROUP BY PointPerson
HAVING SUM([Hours]) > 0
ORDER BY PointPerson
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT PointPerson
FROM DailyTaskHours
WHERE ActivityDate BETWEEN @startDateParam
        AND @endDateParam
        AND len(ltrim(rtrim(PointPerson)))>0
GROUP BY PointPerson
HAVING SUM([Hours]) > 0
ORDER BY PointPerson
```